Mac Studio always requires password after sleep
tl;dr
Mac Studio Touch ID works for everything except for waking the machine after the keyboard has been switched off. MacBook Pro Touch ID works for waking from sleep. How can this be, and how can I fix it?
 

 
Longer version
I have two Macs running Sonoma: a MacBook Pro (M1 2020), and a Mac Studio (M1 Max 2022) with a wireless Apple Keyboard with Touch ID.
I have biometrics (fingerprints) set up on both machines, and I can use my fingerprint to auto-fill passwords in Safari, use Apple Pay, etc., on both machines. I can also use my fingerprint to unlock the screen if it has been locked, whether due to inactivity or manually, and if the machine has been in sleep mode for a short period of time.
The annoyance I’m facing appears when the machine has been in sleep mode for some time – I don’t know exactly how long, but about 15–20 minutes seems to be enough, perhaps less. Edit: It seems perhaps it’s not (only?) the length of time, but (also?) whether the keyboard has been switched off. If I put the Mac Studio to sleep, switch the keyboard off and then on again after 20 seconds and wake the computer up, the issue appears.
I put the MacBook Pro to sleep by closing the lid; I put the Mac Studio to sleep by pressing the Touch ID and then Escape.
When I open the MacBook Pro after a period of sleep mode, I can still unlock it using my fingerprint: I see a lock screen with the text “Touch ID or Enter Password” and no password input field (same as if I just lock the screen). Once a week or so, it’ll ask me for my password with a password input field and a text saying “Password required to enable Touch ID” (or words to that effect), but the rest of the time, I just put my finger to the Touch ID and it immediately unlocks.
However, when I open my Mac Studio after a period of sleep and/or after having switched off the keyboard, it requires a password every time. I get a lock screen with a password input field and words to the effect of “Enter password to unlock your Mac” – and Touch ID does nothing.
If I hit Escape (to put the computer back in sleep mode) and then wake it up again, Touch ID once again works.
The System Preferences settings for Lock Screen and Touch ID & Password are identical on the two machines (apart from the number of minutes before the display turns off and the extra battery-based one on the MBP) – here from the Mac Studio:


Notably, Use Touch ID to unlock your Mac is enabled, and as mentioned, unlocking from the screen saver/locked screen works as expected; it’s only unlocking from sleep mode that doesn’t work.
What may be causing the Mac Studio to ignore this setting only after a period of time in sleep mode or after the keyboard has been switched off? Is there a way to fix it so it works the same as on the MacBook Pro?

"The difference" is?

@SolarMike Oops, that was an accidental remnant. The thought that occurred to me was that it may be related to switching off the keyboard (as indeed does seem to be the case), but I changed my mind and incorporated it into the question instead of adding it on as an edit at the end.

Is there any reason you switch off your keyboard regularly? I have the same keyboard and it's on all the time. ("Doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Well, don't do it, then!"....)

@benwiggy To save power. If I leave them on 24/7, the mouse and keyboard last about a month or so on a full charge; switching them off after use increases that to about fourfold.

What happens if you use the MacBook after switching it off?

@mmmmmm If I switch it off completely (i.e., reboot), then I believe I have to enter a password – this is the same for all Macs and iDevices, as far as I know. But I virtually never reboot either of the computers unless I’m installing updates.

In your first screenshot, the switches to allow password hints and show a message when locked are grayed out. Are they also grayed on the MacBook? Are any profiles installed on the Studio, or has it ever been enrolled in MDM?

@LincD. Yup, those two settings are off on the MacBook as well (they’re not greyed out as such, that’s just what System Preference toggles look like when they’re not turned on). Google tells me MDM is likely Mobile Device Management, which neither machine has ever been enrolled in; and if you mean profiles like the ones found in Privacy & Security → Profiles, then there are no profiles installed on either machine.

Probably this is a bug, and it's unlikely to be fixed because most people don't switch off their keyboard every time they're away from the machine. You have a workaround.

As noted this happens when you switch the keyboard off - in both the separate keyboard and the macBook. It just so happens that you can't switch the MacBook keyboard off without turning the whole machine off. So it is a consistent issue

@mmmmmm I suppose that’s one way of looking at it… It’s not quite consistent, though. When waking from sleep, if I click the Touch ID again to put the computer back to sleep, and after a few seconds wake it up again, then Touch ID works. That’s not the case after a reboot, where it still requires a password if I try the same trick.

That is the point I make if you reboot or turn off the keyboard it is different to just sleeping the keyboard.

@mmmmmm There’s no such thing as ‘sleeping the keyboard’. The keyboard goes into power-saving mode automatically after a period of inactivity, but this cannot be triggered by the user, and it’s not the same as sleep mode; it’s comparable to laptops dimming the screen when on battery. Of course it’s different from turning off the keyboard, but turning off/on a peripheral should not affect the OS lock screen.

The issue is that you and I are looking at it in different ways - it is the turning on and off of the keyboard that matters not the OS. I would guess the OS keeps track of the status of they keyboard and if that changes you need to reestablish the connection.

@mmmmmm But if that were so and reestablishing the connection requires inputting the password to enable Touch ID, then why does the ‘trick’ work? Hitting Escape (not Touch ID as I accidentally wrote above) is not inputting a password, and yet it seems to enable Touch ID just the same.

I would try and make sure this isn’t a Bluetooth issue.
Connect your keyboard via USB on the Studio and test. Then take the keyboard to the portable mic and test both Bluetooth and USB. Hopefully it isn’t something that needs a repair and is software.
Second I would test with screen lock before sleep and then right after a manual sleep. Narrowing down the timing might help with other ideas before you seek official Apple support to rule out a repair need.
